# Finding Values with only one key in a key/value pair efficiently time-complexity wise : Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary, time-complexity

I wish to retrieve values from a Java Key/Value pair (Map with one-to-many mapping) having only one corresponding key without looping over all the values in the Map and turning it into a `O(n)` complexity. 
The Key/Value data structure would be like:

> K1 --> V1, V2
>   K2 --> V1, V2, V3
>   K3 --> V1
>   K4 --> 
>   K5 --> V4, V2

Would appreciate if anyone has any recommendations around the same or if this can be made better time-complexity wise.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a key/value pair where the value is known but the key is not, and you want to use the value to look up the key?

Comment: A second question: does "having only one corresponding key" mean that this Map structure is guaranteed to have a 1-to-1 mapping between keys and values? That is, each value is unique when compared to all other values in the Map?

Comment: From the documentation for `TreeMap`'s `containsValue`: `This operation will probably require time linear in the map size for most implementations.` So it assumes linear merely to find out if the map even contains the value at all in the first place, never mind any other guarantees or returning a key.

Comment: @ Loduwijk: Both the Keys and Values are known. It is a one-to-many mapping. Have updated the post.
@Gnon: It would but trying to find an optimum way to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google's guava there is a very nice BiMap class where you can look-up both keys and values (it is backed by two Maps).

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

EDITED: After clarification. I think my answer does not change much. Guava has also very nice MultiMap interface (and several implementations of it) which you can most likely use for your purpose.

Comment: @Jarek: Does MultiMap do better than O(n) or in other words for all the unique values, finding if it has only one key associated to it.

Comment: You could use "reverse MultiMap" for that. You could have not only multimap key-> values but also another one value->keys build in parallell. A kind of "BiMultiMap" (but I think such a structure is not readily available in guava and you'd have to keep both maps updated by your own wrapper (but using existing guava's multimaps the code would be very simple).

Comment: Of course. But creating structure is one thing and searching it is another. If you have a case where you create the structure once (or rarely) and search it many-many times (or very often) this approach is  very efficient (it is equivalent of building cache).

Comment: Makes sense. However in my case i have to create the structure and then search for the relevant values in the structure.

Comment: If you need to build such a structure, it is always o(n) at least (you need to read n values)... so i don't see a problem really.

Comment: I was wondering if i could do better than that. Right now, time-complexity is like O(1) to get all the keys -> O(n) to build the Map  -> O(1) to get all the unique values in the Map -> O(n) to retrieve values with only one key.

Comment: which makes it O(n) at least. You cannot do better than that. O(n) + O(n) = O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Given my above assumptions in my comments, the most straightforward way to do this which comes to mind quickly is to have two structures. Either two maps, where the keys in one are the values in the other and vice-versa, or to have two sorted lists for which you can perform a binary search on either and the result you find has a reference to the sister-element in the other list; this would give you o(log(n)).

If you go with two mirror-image maps as mentioned above, you could have o(1) if they are both `HashMap`s. You could have a HashMap and a HashMap, and then have a structure which encapsulates keeping them synchronized.

Comment: First of all, creating another structure would add to the time-complexity. There is an O(n) operation already happening which loops through all the keys once and creates the Map.

Comment: Not really. As Jarek pointed out to you above, o(n)+o(n)=o(n). It is still linear time. In reality, however, it would approximately double the time to create the structure in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more specific?
What properties describe your keys and values?
Assuming your keys are unique, you could have multiple values mapped to a key using a LinkedList or an ArrayList. To retrieve all values you just have to take a reference to the specific data structure but at one point or another you will definetely need to traverse the list so, yes, it will take O(n) time if you want to check each element for something. On the other hand, you could use a Binary Tree or a Red-Black Tree (or something else) for your values making searching among them much more efficient (as I said these depends on your value's properties).